# duplicate symbol linker error due to libWeANDSFLibrary.a(ASIReachability.o)

Tags: ios, iphone, asihttprequest, linker-errors

I am using **ASI** (`ASIHTTPRequest`, `ASIDownloadCache`, `Reachability` etc) request. Now in my project, I am using `reachability.h` and `.m` file.I have added one third party library and in that library I came to know that they are also using **ASI** library.
But as per my knowledge they are using `ASIReachability` class instead of `Reachability`. So I added that `.h` file as well.

Still I am getting linker error which says :

```
duplicate symbol _kInternetConnection in:

    /Users/goutham.v/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_TWCable-fyaebjpvvaprmgdgtirhzshodpky/Build/Intermediates/My TWCable.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/My TWCable.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability.o
    /Users/goutham.v/Desktop/SVN/TWC_BC/12Mar2014_TWCBC/weandsf/iphonesimulator/libWeANDSFLibrary.a(ASIReachability.o)

duplicate symbol _kLocalWiFiConnection in:

    /Users/goutham.v/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_TWCable-fyaebjpvvaprmgdgtirhzshodpky/Build/Intermediates/My TWCable.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/My TWCable.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability.o
    /Users/goutham.v/Desktop/SVN/TWC_BC/12Mar2014_TWCBC/weandsf/iphonesimulator/libWeANDSFLibrary.a(ASIReachability.o)

duplicate symbol _kReachabilityChangedNotification in:

    /Users/goutham.v/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_TWCable-fyaebjpvvaprmgdgtirhzshodpky/Build/Intermediates/My TWCable.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/My TWCable.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability.o
    /Users/goutham.v/Desktop/SVN/TWC_BC/12Mar2014_TWCBC/weandsf/iphonesimulator/libWeANDSFLibrary.a(ASIReachability.o)
duplicate symbol _kConnectionDown in:

    /Users/goutham.v/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_TWCable-fyaebjpvvaprmgdgtirhzshodpky/Build/Intermediates/My TWCable.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/My TWCable.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability.o
    /Users/goutham.v/Desktop/SVN/TWC_BC/12Mar2014_TWCBC/weandsf/iphonesimulator/libWeANDSFLibrary.a(ASIReachability.o)
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please help me. Thanking you.

Comment: It's being compiled twice (probably also in ASI, as you stated).  So try removing the .m file you've added and leave the .h file in place, so you can take advantage of the reachability code that's buried deep in the ASI library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've receive **duplicate symbol** error. So you've to search this string `_kConnectionDown`, `_kReachabilityChangedNotification`, `_kLocalWiFiConnection`,  `_kInternetConnection`, and remove duplication from files. I think, you may import `Reachability` class twice, one from `libWeANDSFLibrary.a` and another from `ASI`. Check this. Hope, help you.

Comment: There is only one reachability file in my prom.When i removed rechability.m,it was showing error for reachability.so i think that is not an issue and when i search these strings ,it was showing 0 result...

Comment: I've searched, Reachability.m contains this string `kConnectionDown`. And also If this static library `libWeANDSFLibrary.a` may contain this string means, it won't show in search.

Comment: yes,,,it was kConnectionDown and i searched _kConnectionDown.sorry...you stated find string and remove duplication from files...what does it mean? and remove from which file reachability or asireachability?

Comment: You've to decide. But my suggestion, remove reachability.h and .m file and instead import `ASIReachability` when you get error according to removal of reachability.

Comment: last question- i have imported reachability file in other classes as well.so should i write #import "asireachability.h" instead of #import "reachability.h" ?

Comment: If you use it means, just import it. otherwise no need. Check it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You may be included that files twice in your project so you should remove any one from the project its all because both getting compiled . **Choose project--> go to Build Phases--> Type filename** which showing it as error and check whether ho many files are there with same name and choose then remove any one from the list

[image]